# Updating MongoDB using PHP simplexml_load_string function variables adding extra '0' key to value

Tags: php, mongodb, xml-parsing, simplexml, php-mongodb

I have a script that is attempting to update a MongoDB collection with an xml response I've received from a server.  I'm envoking simplexml_load_string() on the response.  However, when updating the fields, it's adding an extra '0' key to the value I'm attempting to add.  Here is the code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
if($xml->type == "reject") {
    $status = $xml->type;
    $message = $xml->message;
}
$update = array('$set' => array('status' => $status, 'response' => $message));
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID("..."), "status" : "reject", "response" : "The message." }
```

However, here is the entry that is being saved in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID("..."), "status" : { "0" : "reject" }, "response" : { "0" : "The message." } }
```

Any idea what is happening, or suggestions on how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your post with the actual XML you're receiving?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$xml->type` and `$xml->message` are probably objects, not strings.  You might want to `var_dump` it to see what it actually is and then convert it to a string.

Comment: Yep, it's looking like the string length is being sent, as well - `object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(42) "The amount requested provided is not valid"}`.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like they're strings from that, though.  You could try var_dumping $update to make sure.

Comment: `array(1) { ["$set"]=> array(3) { ["responseTime"]=> string(8) "22:08:18" ["status"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "error" } ["response"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) { [0]=> string(42) "The amount requested provided is not valid" } }}` Is this coming from PHP or is MongoDB adding this?

Comment: There's why, it's storing a SimpleXMLElement.  I am not familiar with SimpleXML, but you'll have to get its innards as a string.

Comment: For now, I got around this by converting the object to an array: `$a = object2array($xml); function object2array($object) { return @json_decode(@json_encode($object),1); }` and then setting `$status = $a['type'];` and `$message = $a['message'];`

Comment: I did try `$status = $xml->type->asXML();` but then I would get "<type>error</type>".  Converting it to an array was easier to deal with.